# assign values of object of class A based on values of object of class compacted A in Java

Tags: java, object, copy

Say I have two classes, **CompactedA** is **A**'s *compact version*:

```
class A {
    private String id = null;
    private List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>;
    private String name = null;
    private String age = null;
}

class CompactedA {
    private String id = null;
    private List<CompactedB> listCompactedB = new ArrayList<CompactedB>;
}

class B {
    private String bId = null;
    private String bName = null;
    private String bAge = null;
}

class CompactedB {
    private String bId = null;
}
```

now I got an object of CompactedA (called `ca`), jsonfied as following:

```
{
    id : '001',   // Id
    [
         { bId : '001b'},
         { bId : '002b'},
         { bId : '003b'},
    ]   // listCompactedB
}
```

How Can I new an A object, say `a`, based on the values of `ca`?

The result of `a` should be:

```
{
    id: '001',
    [
        { bId: '001b', bName: null, bAge: null},
        { bId: '002b', bName: null, bAge: null},
        { bId: '003b', bName: null, bAge: null},
    ],
    name: null,
    age: null
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't provide a particular way for this. You have to write functions to convert from one class to the other by copying and processing each variable.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I searched and find some third party things offer functions like `CopyProperties()`. compactedA and A have different numbers of variables but variables both in them are using the same names, still no easier way?

Comment: There may be libraries which provide such functionality but I don't know one.

Comment: you could use reflection, but writing a converter is much better, as suggested by @MichaelButscher

Comment: if you wanted to go from `A` to `CompactedA` json instead of the other way round, there is a much better way

Comment: @Kartik you mean 'get from one then set into another ' way? Consider if there are deeper objects nested pattern, say B has List<C>, C has list<D>, the conventer will be very complicated

Comment: @Spike Then you need to revisit your design. Make `A` *extend* `CompactA` instead of duplicating fields in 2 classes. Or some other design that better suits your use-case.